# Electric Piano, Organ on Rolling Stones Fool to Cry?

Tags: piano

I'm a longtime jazz woodwinds (hobbiest) player getting into keys. Aside from building my piano chops I'm enjoying the sound design aspect of playing with VST instruments. So I'm like a kid in candy shop learning about different e piano sounds at a level deeper than 'E Piano 1,2,3' on my standalone board.

So I know there's the classic sounds of the Rhodes, Whirlitzer A200, then the clavinet and electric grands. These then sent through pedals and amps for wah, phasers, trembulo. And then the relatives Hammond B3, lesley and the organ family. And mellotrons and tape stuff I know from prog rock love, and synths. But far from able to pick out tones at this point to incorporate into my experimental tracks.

Question is in title - can anyone help me ID the keyboard tones in the intro of Fool to Cry? And what other keyboards are used on this and other tracks? I can't tell if it's a sustained tonebar with effects, organ or what. But love it.

Here's the song/video:

Comment: It's the phase effect from probably MXR phase 90 that's throwing you off the scent. It was used a lot on keys and guitars. However, questions relating to this sort of thing aren't what this site is about, so it will probably be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about identifying instruments belong on the Music Fans SE.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I have read confirms that Mick Jagger played electric piano (a Fender Rhodes) on that track. Nicky Hopkins plays piano on the track, and the string synthesizer as well.

That string synthesizer is believed to be an Arp.

The song (and the album black and blue was recorded between 1974 and 1975, at both Musicland Studios, Munich, West-Germany and Mountain Recording Studios, Montreux, Switzerland.

To the original question, you are hearing the Rhodes mostly.